# how to create title bars for tmux panes

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux

I need to name my tmux panes and view them with a title bar is there any way to set a nano title bar like for each tmux pane? is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to create "nano title bars" in tmux. However, you can have each pane write to the tmux status bar on every command. You'd set your preexec (zsh, as you've tagged this) to something like:

`preexec() { print -Pn '\e]0;$1 | %~\a' }`

That example uses prompt expansion sequences to show the last command and the working dir.

The `FORMATS` section of the tmux manpage describes what can be displayed there.

Comment: I know that, but i need to have separate title or title bar for each pane of tmux (like terminator when splitting window)

Answer (score 0):

```
while sleep 1;do tput sc;tput cup 0 $(($(tput cols)/2));echo "Pane 2";tput rc;done &
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.